# replace a text line with other one in bash

Tags: bash, shell

i want to change a text line in a file with another one for example:
the text that i have

> export
> GEOFIL='/afs/in2p3.fr/home/throng/antares/DETECTOR/r12_c00_s01.det 1
> 1'

and i want to replace it with the new one

> export GEOFIL='/pbs/throng/antares/DETECTOR/r12_c00_s01.det 1 1'

this operation should take place for all files in the current Directory

Answer (score 1):

Use `sed` command:

```bsh
sed -i -e 's#/afs/in2p3.fr/home/#/pbs/#' the_filename
```

Notes:

- `-i` option is for change the content of the file named `the_filename` output create a new file.
- use `#` character in sed `s` command because your text contain `/` character

To execute it on all files of the current directory:

```bsh
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sed -i -e 's#/afs/in2p3.fr/home/#/pbs/#' {} \;
```

Notes:

- `.` : work on current directory
- `-type f` : work only on standard files
- `-maxdepth 1` : work only in current directory (depth = 1), not on sub-directories
- `{}` replaced by the filename found by `find` command
- `\;` is the end of `-exec` option